# Delegation in Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: delegates, smalltalk, pharo

What is the best way of doing delegation in Smalltalk, more specifically in Pharo? I know of the doesNotUnderstand strategy, but it does not delegates subclassResponsability messages.

I was thinking on something that delegates every message send not explicitly implemented on the class to some specified object, like I can do, for example, with @Delegate in Groovy. Is there some already known way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doesNotUndersand:` will only work on methods that the object does not understand (thus the name), so if you already have implemented a method it will not be used (as is the case with `subclassResponsibility`.

If you use Pharo 5 (which should be released this week (May 2016)), you could use MetaLinks. It's a bit of an overkill, however what you are doing doesn't seem right to begin with (why would you want to delegate subclassResponsibility)?

In either case, MetaLinks allow to attach runtime behavior to your methods, for example:

You have some method that you want to delegate

```
MyObject>>someMethod
    ^ self subclassResponsiblity
```

And an object to which you wish to delegate to…

```
MyObject>>delegate
    ^ delegate
```

So you create a MetaLink

```
link := MetaLink new
    metaObject: [ :object :selector :arguments |
        object delegate perform: selector withArguments: argument ];
    selector: #perform:withArguments:;
    arguments: #(object selector arguments);
    control: #instead.
```

Which you can install to any method AST you want.

```
(MyObject>>someMethod ast) link: link.
```

Now every time the method will be called, `instead` (that's what the `control:` does) of executing the method, the arguments of the message (if any) will be given to the block in `metaObject:`.

Although this should work and is extremely powerful mechanism, right now there are serious disadvantages that currently being addressed:

- no documentation
- little tooling support (it's pretty hard to debug)
- a lot of work (we are working on a framework that would ease this as you would want to easily install them and uninstall them everywhere you need, but it's not ready yet, so it has to be done by hand)
- recompilation removes the link (see point above)

### Summary

To summarize, this is possible to do with MetaLinks as I've shown, however at the moment it's quite a lot of work, but we are addressing those issues.

Comment: I understand that a proper delegate mechanism would include those methods with subclassResponsability. I can do delegation by hand by implementing each and every subclassResponsability method and forwarding it to the delegated object. It is how its done in Java. Some languages provide an automatic way of doing delegation, such as Groovy , but as it seems Smalltalk don't. I do think those MetaLinks overkill, what I wanted was something simpler.

Comment: @VitorCruz well you can still override to implementation of subclassResponsibility. It's a method like any other.

Comment: Yes, that was what I said :) "I can do delegation by hand by implementing each and every subclassResponsability method and forwarding it to the delegated object.". But I am too lazy and didn't want to do that.... :)

Comment: I was thinking about what I was trying to do and your question: why I would like to delegateSubclassResponsability? I think it has to do with some vicious from programming with Java where I must, for example, make class B extends class A so that B can be used where A is referenced. So if A has abstract methods, delegation should took them into consideration also. In Smalltalk, I could just create B subclassing from Object, store a reference to A and delegate to it from doesNotUnderstand. The only difference is that the relation between B and A is less explicit. Is that correct?

Comment: Ooops, i would have to store in B a reference to some concrete implementation of A, since A is abstract.

Answer (score 2):

what Peter was talking about is, you can override the
subclassResponsibility, just like you did for the doesNotUnderstand method.
There is no need to override every senders of "self subclassResponsibility".

For example, just delegate to the implementation of doesNotUnderstand

```
subclassResponsibility

^ self
    doesNotUnderstand: (Message selector: thisContext sender selector 
                                arguments: thisContext sender arguments)
```

Comment: I wasn't manage to make this work (I have tried this already). In Pharo 5 using this code and inspecting the result of an delegated operation shows me the receiver object. Trying to debug freezes the image, i have no clue why. I will investigate further later.

Comment: I figured out what is happening. Normally methods that call subclassResponsability do not return its return, for example:  

`someMessage>>: self subclassResponsability` 
 
 
In order to do what you suggested the method should be implemented like this: 

`someMessage>>: ^self subclassResponsability`

But that is not the case for all senders of subclassResponsability I saw.

Comment: Concluding: As it seems, overriding the implementation of subclassResponsability does not solves the problem.